# How do I access a form's control from another thread?

Tags: multithreading, forms, visual-c++, variable-declaration

Using VC++ 2010.

I want to access a form's control from a class in another thread.. and can't figure out the best (or any) way to do this.  How can I pass a reference of my form instance?  Im using createthread() as opposed to the managed version, wanting to make my app compatible with XP.

I've tried passing a reference and other values in a struct through the lpParameter, but I can't seem to figure out how to declare the reference properly.

```
ref class SZClass {
    private:
        FMain ^bound_form;
        int server_port;
    public:
        void BindForm(FMain ^bf);
        void Initialize(int sp)
}

struct param_data {
    public:
        FMain ^form_tobind;
        int port_num;
}
```

are giving me errors:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
```

FMain is the name of my form class, and I have a delegate method already set up to make it multithread safe:

```
public:
    FMain(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

    void FMain::PrintConsole(std::string mzg) {
        String ^Smzg = marshal_as<String^>(mzg);
        if (this->textBox1->InvokeRequired) {
            SetTextDelegate^ d =  gcnew SetTextDelegate(this, &FMain::PrintConsole);
            this->Invoke(d, gcnew array<Object^> { Smzg });
        } else {
            textBox1->Text += Smzg;
            textBox1->SelectionStart = textBox1->TextLength;
        }
    }
```

How do I declare a reference to my form?
Or is there an easier or better way to do this?

Comment: It is just the typical Smzg problem, you have a circular dependency between headers.  The FMain class needs to know about the SZClass and the SZClass needs to know about FMain.  You have to do the C++ dance with a forward declaration and splitting declaration and definition between .h and .cpp files.  You need somebody to review your code btw, ask a team member or friend.

Comment: i have a .h and .cpp for the class, is that not enough? do i have to do the same for my form class? and in which ones would i include which?

Comment: It is not enough when I listed three things and you did two of them.  Google "c++ forward declaration", first hit is good.   Write this in C# when you are not familiar with the C++ language.

Comment: I learned c++ 15 yrs ago on Borland and am recently picking it up again on vc++, i have no experience with c#, and dont wish to try... i was just looking for a little clarificiation

Comment: i am now trying to separate my fmain.h into fmain.h and fmain.cpp.. but i now have designer errors for which im trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what forms library you're using, but the general rule of thumb for your question is, "Don't."

Unless you have a peculiar GUI library, Windows UI is thread-affinitized. All access to UI elements should be done via the ui's affinitized thread. Manipulating UI state from an unaffinitized execution context should be done by marshaling the update request to the affinitized context. It should not be done directly.

Comment: well, i already have a delegate function in my form class to make sure it's safe, i just can't figure out how to make the connection from the new thread to the form.. see updated above.